# Slider animation depending on window size

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to make "animation" to go to specific (fixed) position depending on screen resolution (window size)?
Because if I resize window or website is opened in other resolution screen, animation doesn't fit properly to site. Fluid design would solve the problem, but I don't have time for making that kind of changes..
Thank you in advance!

```
$("img.topimage").hide(); 

  // slide in 
  var car = $('<img src="images/ccc.png" />'); 

     car.css('position', 'absolute'); 
     car.css('top', 123); 
     car.css('left', -690); 
     car.css('z-index', 1000); 

  $('html').append(car); 

  car.animate({ 
     left: '+=1025'// 
  }, { 
     duration: 2000, 
     complete: function() { 
        create_slides(); 

        $("img.topimage").show(); 

        car.remove(); 
     } 
  } 
  );
```

Comment: Calculate the coordinate based on `window.innerwidth` or `window.innerHeight`. e.g.: 100 pixels to the left of window width: `window.innerWidth-100`.